# Accessing and modifying Wifi state in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I was wondering if I could get a second (or many for that matter) set of eyes to help me with this. I cannot for the life of me figure what is causing this. Basically, this is just a wireless activity that allows you to change the wifi state. However, my code is kicking out a nullPointerException at the call of getWiFi();. Its also pointing to line 123 but I see nothing wrong. Can anyone see why this would crash? My permissions in the manifest are correct to my knowledge. Here is the code from the java file. Line 89 is where getWifi(); is called. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code for WirelessManager.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
        import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.Button;

        public class WirelessManager extends Activity {
    //index values to access the elements in the TextView array.
    private final int SSTRENGTH = 0;
    private final int WIFISTATE = 1;
    private final int IPADD     = 2;
    private final int MACADD    = 3;
    private final int SSID      = 4;
    private final int LINKSPD   = 5;    

    private TextView[] data_labels;
    private TextView name_label;
    private TextView enable_label;
    private Button state_button;
    private Button back_button;
    private WifiManager wifi;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.info_layout);

        wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        TextView[] titles = new TextView[6];
        data_labels = new TextView[6];

        int[] left_views = {R.id.first_title, R.id.second_title, R.id.third_title,
                       R.id.fourth_title, R.id.fifth_title};

        /*R.layout.info_layout is the same layout used for directory info.
         *Re-using the layout for this activity, so id tag names may not make sense,
         *but are in the correct order.
         */
        int[] right_views = {R.id.dirs_label, R.id.files_label, R.id.time_stamp,
                             R.id.total_size, R.id.free_space};
        String[] labels = {"Signal strength", "WIFI State", "ip address",
                          "mac address", "SSID", "link speed"};

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            titles[i] = (TextView)findViewById(left_views[i]);
            titles[i].setText(labels[i]);

            data_labels[i] = (TextView)findViewById(right_views[i]);
            data_labels[i].setText("N/A");
        }

        name_label = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name_label);
        enable_label = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.path_label);
        state_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back_button);
        back_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.zip_button);
        back_button.setText(" Back ");

        state_button.setOnClickListener(new ButtonHandler());
        back_button.setOnClickListener(new ButtonHandler());

        ImageView icon = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.info_icon);
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.wireless);

        get_wifi();
    }

    private void get_wifi() {
        WifiInfo info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
        int state = wifi.getWifiState();
        int strength = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(info.getRssi(), 5);
        boolean enabled = wifi.isWifiEnabled();

        name_label.setText(info.getSSID());
        enable_label.setText(enabled ?"Your wifi is enabled" :"Your wifi is not enabled");
        state_button.setText(enabled ?"Disable wifi" : "Enable wifi");

        switch(state) {
            case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED:
                data_labels[WIFISTATE].setText(" Enabled");
                break;
            case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED:
                data_labels[WIFISTATE].setText(" Disabled");
                break;
            case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLING:
                data_labels[WIFISTATE].setText(" Being Disabled");
                break;
            case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING:
                data_labels[WIFISTATE].setText(" Being Enabled");
                break;
            case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN:
                data_labels[WIFISTATE].setText(" Unknown");
                break;
        }
        if(enabled) {
            data_labels[IPADD].setText(FileManager.integerToIPAddress(info.getIpAddress()));
            data_labels[MACADD].setText(info.getMacAddress());
            data_labels[SSID].setText(info.getSSID());
            data_labels[LINKSPD].setText(info.getLinkSpeed() + " Mbps");
            data_labels[SSTRENGTH].setText("strength " + strength);
        }else {
            data_labels[IPADD].setText("N/A");
            data_labels[MACADD].setText(info.getMacAddress());
            data_labels[SSID].setText("N/A");
            data_labels[LINKSPD].setText("N/A");
            data_labels[SSTRENGTH].setText("N/A");
        }
    }

    private class ButtonHandler implements OnClickListener {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(v.getId() == R.id.back_button) {
                if(wifi.isWifiEnabled()){
                    wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
                    state_button.setText("Enable wifi");
                }else {
                    wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
                    state_button.setText("Disable wifi");
                    get_wifi();
                }   
            }else if(v.getId() == R.id.zip_button)
                finish();
        }
    }

}


Code for AndroidManifest.xml


        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="coxxxxxxxxxx"
      android:versionCode="100"
      android:versionName="1.0.0"
      android:installLocation="auto">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" >



        <activity android:name=".Settings" android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <activity android:name=".ProcessManager" android:label="@string/manager_act" />
        <activity android:name=".WirelessManager" android:label="Wireless Information" />
        <activity android:name=".ApplicationBackup" android:label="Installed Applications" />



                <activity android:name=".Main"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".AudioPlayblack"
                  android:label="@string/media_dialog"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />

        <activity android:name=".DirectoryInfo" android:enabled="true"
                  android:label="@string/dir_info">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/manager" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".HelpManager"
                  android:label="XXXXXXXXX"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />


 </application>
            <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                      android:normalScreens="true"
                      android:largeScreens="true" />
            <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"
              android:maxSdkVersion="10"/>

         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>


       </manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off by 1 error.  Your for loop getting the views goes i<5, but you're accessing i=5 with LINKSP.  Increase your for loop and all arrays by 1.

Comment: WOW!!! Thanks man....I dont know how I was missing that. You nailed it. Works fine now. I looked at that for at least 1 and a half hours today an could not see it! I cant thank you enough!